# How do I show a MessageBox prompt when the user has clicked the cross in the title bar

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently developing a C# Windows Form Application.

After the user has login through the loginForm, it will be brought to the mainForm.

I would like to code it in a way that after the user click the cross on the title bar in the mainForm, there would be a prompt asking the user "This will close the application. Confirm?"
followed by a yes and no button.

If yes, another box will be displayed, "Application Closed!"

If no, the messagebox will just close and the application will continue running.

My current code is :

```
private void mainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("This will close down the whole application. Confirm?", "Close Application", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The application has been closed successfully.", "Application Closed!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
    }
    else
    {
        this.Activate();
    }   
}
```

however it does not work.

Firstly I have no idea why the messagebox pops up twice in order for the whole thing to close.

Secondly if i click no, the form closes as well and I am not able to bring it back.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To cancel the closing of the form, in your else statement you need `e.Cancel = true;`.
You don't need the explicit Exit in your true case.

Give this a try

```
private void mainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("This will close down the whole application. Confirm?", "Close Application", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The application has been closed successfully.", "Application Closed!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

    }
    else
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.Activate();
    }   
}
```

I assume your second MessageBox to say it has closed if for testing purposes only.

You probably only want.

```
private void mainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("This will close down the whole application. Confirm?", "Close Application", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) != DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    } 
}
```

Notice the statement checks to see if they didn't hit yes, rather than if they hit cancel. This means that if they hit the x on the dialog box it won't be counted as a confirmation.

**EDIT: If mainForm isn't the main form**

Okay, I think I've got what you're asking now.

What I would do is put the code I have in my second code block above in the FormClosing, and then in the FormClosed event handler have this

```
private void mainForm_FormClosed(Object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("The application has been closed successfully.", "Application Closed!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for your reply. it does works. but not totally the result that i wanted. the reason why i coded in the System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit(); is because i wanted the whole application to end. not just that form itself as it is not the main form and i have multiple form. so how do i go about doing that?

Comment: Oh, the mainForm isn't the main form?. Okay, then just add the exit call back into the true case.

Comment: hi i'm sorry. still quite unsure about this. what do you mean by that?

Comment: hi, that was also part of my initial problem. the point is when you do that, it prompts the window twice instead of once. so you would be clicking 4 windows of yes yes yes yes if i were to code it using the first box of code you have typed.

Comment: @Thomas okay, I think I've got you now. Can you try what I've updated above? I'm unable to verify it at the moment.

Comment: thanks ray! it works. i have edited my post on top for the final solution instead! as there is still a small flaw in your coding as doing that way will still prompt the confirmation messagebox twice.

Comment: @Thomas. Cool. You should mark this as the accepted answer. There is no need to add the answer to your question text.

Answer (score 3):

This should help you

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to close?", "Close", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No)
            e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look to Cancel property in `FormClosingEventArgs`:
This should work:

```
  private void mainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("This will close down the whole application. Confirm?", "Close Application", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The application has been closed successfully.", "Application Closed!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        } 
        else 
        {
          e.Cancel = true; 
        }
    }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formclosingeventargs.aspx

Comment: hi im sorry but i didn't get what you are trying to say. where is the part that i called it twice?

Comment: You shouldn't need the `Exit()` call here, as the app will be in the process of closing anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you need:

```
private void mainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("This will close down the whole application. Confirm?", "Close Application", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The application has been closed successfully.", "Application Closed!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
    else
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }   
}
```

**Edit:** to answer your first question, see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894.aspx). When you call `Exit()` in your application, a `FormClosing` event is raised for all open forms, including `mainForm` (which is still open), so the event gets raised twice. Normally I would expect something like this to result in an infinite recursion and a literal stack overflow, but I assume .NET is smart enough to prevent this.

On a related note, you should really never have your program close by calling `Exit()` - it's kind of a code smell.

Answer (score 1):

To get the desired functionality, try this code instead:

```
private void mainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("This will close down the whole application. Confirm?", "Close Application", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The application has been closed successfully.", "Application Closed!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        //no need to do anything here.
    }
    else
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var GetInput = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to Delete?", "Confirm Deletion",MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

if (GetInput == MessageBoxResult.OK)
{ 
   //do what you like
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code works perfectly for me with no errors.

```
private void exiteProToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("message", "title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
    else
    {
        this.Activate();
    }   
}
```