# Cancel Application Exit

Tags: c#, winforms

My application is closing when I press Alt + F4. How I will do to have a MessageBox to show first for confirmation before exiting and if No is response the applcation will not continue to close?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I show a MessageBox prompt when the user has clicked the cross in the title bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955244/how-do-i-show-a-messagebox-prompt-when-the-user-has-clicked-the-cross-in-the-tit)

Comment: What application? [Alt + F4](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/question266.htm) closes the current window

Comment: You could do this by adding an event for Mainform closing. In that method open a messagebox and check the result. Finally set e.Cancel = true

Comment: Wondering why this question is downvoted?  Agree that it is a duplicate and the english is not correct..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Handle the [`Form.Closing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing.aspx) event, which takes a `CancelEventArgs` as parameter. In that handler, show your messagebox. If the user wishes to cancel, set the property `.Cancel` of the event args to `true`, like this:

```
private void Form1_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    var result = MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to exit?", "Are you sure?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if (result == DialogResult.No)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the answers already posted here, don't be the dork that hangs the complete system:

```
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CloseReason != CloseReason.UserClosing)
        {
           e.Cancel = false;
           return;
        }

        // other logic with Messagebox
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Asking the question on system shutdown is still valid (e.g. if you want to cancel shutdown because you've not saved your document). Still, a good point!

Comment: @DanPuzey - Maybe, but you would have to think about  AutoSave and timeout options first, and the risks of blocking it.

Answer (score 0):

On [FormClosing() event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing.aspx) add this code:

```
private void MyForm_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if(MessageBox.Show("Are you sure want to exit the App?", "Test", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No)
    {
      e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```